# Segfaults and referencing struct arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

I've got a project that involves creating a text game. I'm creating a struct for each player and putting them in an array. I'm then trying to pass in data and then pass by pointer the array to other functions, however I keep on getting segmentation faults (Although on the odd occasion working fine). I've summarised below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  char name[9];
  int cardsHeld;
  int hand[8];
} Player;

void printNames(Player** playerArray)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", playerArray[i]->name);
  }
}


void gamesetup()
{
  int count;

  fprintf(stdout, "How many players will be partaking in 'The Game'? ( 1 - 5)\n");
  fscanf(stdin, "%d", &count);

  Player** playerArray = (Player**)malloc(sizeof(Player*) * count);

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    playerArray[i] = (Player*) malloc(sizeof(Player));
    fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the name for player %d.\n\n", i + 1);
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", playerArray[i]->name);
  }

  printNames(playerArray);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  gamesetup();

  return 0;
}
```

My questions are;

1. Is the fscanf getting the address of the Player.name member? I'm getting confused whether the -> operator should deference the value of the struct member or since its in an array the address?
2. I'm not sure why it works sometimes but not others. If it works sometimes fundamentally it should be ok. Is the malloc function allocating memory it should not or is the fscanf putting data in the wrong place.

Thank you.

-EDIT-

Changed the code so it is in a complete program that appears to work without seg faults. I think that my issues arise from not freeing the memory before termination is messing it up next time I run it without compiling first. I'm still not sure why fscanf works as in my mind the argument playerArray[i]->name is returning the value, not the address.

Comment: Can you write that into a complete, compilable program (with a `main()` function etc)? Minimize it to the point where the problem still appears. Right now it's hard to tell if the issue is with this snippet or code, or outside of it. Also, set the compiler warnings on, and see what the compiler says.

Comment: Names have 8 max chars? Then `gameController(playerArray);` remains mysterious to us

Comment: The "value" of an array is the address of its first element.

Comment: " I think that my issues arise from not freeing the memory before termination is messing it up next time ..." -- your thinking is incorrect, the root cause is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out where I was confused. Thank you for all your help in the comments.

The member I am accessing in my array is a string of chars so the first member is a pointer. By using fscanf(stdin, "%s",playerArray[i]->name); This deferenced the pointer (an address) so it works. I was getting in a muddle as it was an member of an array of structs. The segfaults were caused by me messing with the code to try and fix what already worked.